# How do I search for whole words in Chrome's source code editor?

Tags: google-chrome, regex

The find and replace dialog in Chrome's built-in source code editor (Chrome DevTools) can use regular expressions, and it has currently no checkbox for searching for whole words. Is there a regular expression to make Chrome find and replace whole words?

Comment: Did you try `\bthe_pattern\b` or `\<the_pattern\>`?

Comment: @IsmailS This question was migrated from [webapps.se] My comment was posted before the migration. In cases like this, please just flag the comment as "It's no longer required"

Comment: @Rubén, I see.. Sure. I didn't knew it migrated from Web Applications.